# How do i remove default initial value of a textbox bound to decimal

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

What are the options to remove default initial value 0 in textbox which is bind to decimal property?

```
private decimal _Quantity;
public decimal Quantity
    {
        get { return _Quantity; }
        set { _Quantity = value; OnPropertyChanged("Quantity"); }
    }
```

xaml code

```
textbox text={Binding Quantity}
```

Comment: Changing the property type to `decimal?` should work - that allows you to clearly differentiate between 'not filled in yet' (`null`) and 'filled in with 0' (`0`).

Comment: but its a UI req. why would you change your datatype for it ?

Comment: @Muds: because a UI usually reflects the state of a program, and 'not filled in yet' is apparently a valid state, one that cannot be expressed by a `decimal` property only. Well, unless the value `0` is given a special meaning, but I think that's making things too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a style like this

```
<TextBox>   
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>    
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
<TextBox.Style>             
<TextBox>
```

Comment: doesn't work.Error 2 Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Text'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property. Line 233 Position 53.

Comment: put this style in textbox.style

Comment: @ConfuseD: Changing the opening `<Style>` tag to `<Style TargetType="TextBox">` should make it work. Alternately, you can change the setter to `<Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="" />`.